# Parse <img> tag that lies within the <description></description> of an rss2 feed item

Tags: objective-c, ios, xml-parsing, for-xml-path, gdataxml

What I try to accomplish is get the src attribute of an RSS2 feed item using `GDataXML`. The feed's item xml is like this:

```
<item>
  <title>BlackBerry EMEA servers crash</title>
  <link>http://www.mysite.com/?p=672</link>
  <comments>http://www.mysite.com/?p=672#comments</comments>
  <pubDate>Mon, 10 Oct 2011 21:11:24 +0000</pubDate>
  <dc:creator>acreator</dc:creator>
  <category><![CDATA[Latest News]]></category>
  <description><![CDATA[<span class="image-rss"><a href="http://www.mysite.com/?p=672"><img title="BlackBerry EMEA servers crash" src="http://www.mysite.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/blackberry-thumb-medium-300x187.jpg" alt="BlackBerry EMEA servers crash" width="200" height="124" /></a></span><br/>yada yada yada]]></description>
</item>
```

The code I am currently using, parses pretty fine the `<description>`, `<title>`, `<link>`; and `<pubdate>`; but fails on `<img>`;. Here is the code:

```
NSArray *channels = [rootElement elementsForName:@"channel"];
  for (GDataXMLElement *channel in channels) {            

    NSArray *items = [channel elementsForName:@"item"];
    for (GDataXMLElement *item in items) {

        GDataXMLElement *articleDesc = [item elementForChild:@"description"];
        NSArray *imgs = [articleDesc nodesForXPath:@"//img[@src]" error:nil];

        NSString *articleTitle = [item valueForChild:@"title"];
        NSString *url = [item valueForChild:@"link"];            
        NSString *articleDateString = [item valueForChild:@"pubDate"];

        Article *entry = [[[Article alloc] initWithTitle:articleTitle 
                                                     url:url 
                                                    date:articleDate] autorelease];
        [entries addObject:entry];
    }      
}
```

When I print to console the description of **`articleDesc`**, I get the following:

```
GDataXMLElement 0x70503b0: {type:1 name:description xml:"<description>&lt;span class="image-rss"&gt;&lt;a href="http://www.mysite.com/?p=672"&gt;&lt;img title="BlackBerry EMEA servers crash" src="http://www.mysite.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/blackberry-thumb-medium-300x187.jpg" alt="BlackBerry EMEA servers crash" width="200" height="124" /&gt;&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/span&gt;&lt;br/&gt;RIM has confirmed that…</description>"}
```

Is it possible to parse the **`src` attribute** using the "fast" `GDataXML` or I'll have to do it using regular expressions?

All suggestions are very welcome.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem and found the solution. It should be like this:

```
NSArray *imgs = [articleDesc nodesForXPath:@"//img/@src" error:nil];
```